Geometry Nodes : Unexpected Grid Node behavior (spacing, seamless)
I'm really new to geometry nodes and I am trying to get a simple grid of cubes, but things aren't working as I expected.
I thought making a 10x10 grid at a size of 1m² and placing cubes 1/10m² would give me a seamless grid.

But I end up having some spacing between the cubes 

If anyone knows how to fix it, or even better knows why this is happening, I would love to hear it :D
(I am using Blender 4.0)

Haven't got my math head on to explain it at the moment, but try using 11 x 11 vertices on the Grid node...

@JohnEason I was tempted to suggest 11 × 11 as well, but since the question does not give any information if the goal is to have 10 × 10 cubes, or cubes of 0.1 edge length or maybe cubes filling an area of 1 m × 1 m I stuck to the explanation why there are gaps between the cubes  :-)

@GordonBrinkmann It was very late at night when I posted that comment1 :^)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error

You have a grid of 10 × 10 vertices with a dimension of 1 m in X and Y direction.
10 vertices mean there are 9 gaps between the vertices. 9 gaps with a length of 1 m altogether means the distances between the vertices are:
$$\frac{1\text{ m}}{9}\approx 0.111\text{ m}$$
I would call this expected Grid node behaviour.

Thanks, that helps a ton !
My misunderstanding came from the fact I thought points where placed on each face's center, this is indeed very predictable behavior now that you've enlightened me

@SillyNeve could you kindly click the checkmark on the left of this answer post so we can mark this question as answered.

@SillyNeve But you know simple square or rectangular faces (which a grid basically is just made of) is built from vertices on each corner, don't you?

Yes ! My wording isn't the best sorry. When I said : " My misunderstanding came from the fact I thought points where placed on each face's center" I forgot to say I also wrongly thought the terms faces and vertices were interchangeable in this scenario.
